# How can I control ubuntu system startup when certain conditions exist

Tags: dual-boot, power-management, battery

I have a travel laptop running dual boot (Ubuntu 17.04 desktop and Windows 10 Home). I want to control the startup, such that if the laptop lid is closed and/or no AC power is connected (eg. in a backpack or briefcase), so that one can terminate the startup and power off.

The laptop is waking up in the early AM, most likely due to a scheduled event on Windows 10.  The dual-boot defaults into Ubuntu and it currently gets as far as the login and stays there until the battery dies or I open the lid and login.

I see that Ubuntu's systemd software has a HandleLidSwitch in the logind.conf file.  This appears to require a transition in the state.

As everyone knows excess heat is a killer of computer and a backpack or briefcase is a perfect environment to hold heat.

Comment: if it is powered off, it should not start on it's own. Are you sure that you are shutting it down and not suspending it.

Comment: I either  perform a "Hibernate"  in Windows 10 or a "Shut down..." on  Ubuntu.  I will pay more attention to the last operation performed  when I observe the next wake-up.   I am in the process of configuring VirtualBox  and/or VMware Workstation on Ubuntu on my newer hardware (HP Spectre x360).   In the process of doing a full restoreable backup at this time.

Comment: hmmm, even a hibernate shouldn't start the machine. A sleep might though. I could see a "sleep" state waking to do updates in windows, then rebooting. Note: if you share partitions between Win10 and Ubuntu it is advisable to turn off fast start and hibernate since file corruption is possible.

Comment: Both "sleep" and "suspend"  leave the "Power On" button light blinking and this is not observed when I put the laptop in my backpack.  Your reply and how I was going to respond got me to investigate the hybrid-startup feature that was introduced in Windows 8 & 10.   The following link explains the feature and issues one will encounter, like shared partitions you mentioned:  https://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/

Comment: suspend = sleep. so with either one you are not turning off the computer. A computer that is powered off  can not start itself.